# remove support for 'Categories' for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy

How would I go about removing support for Wordpress 'Categories' for a custom post type? I've created a custom taxonomy for the post type, so there is no need for the standard categories.

Oddly, I thought this would be easy to find out how to do via Google but I can't find anything on it. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you share your code where register_post_type  is being called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the array of arguments to [register_post_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)
 there is a parameter "taxonomies". If category is not specified there, then it shouldn't appear with that post type.

Comment: But it does. (I added it however before, but I changed my mind and can't make it disappear)